# Split screen into 4 windows natively without numpad

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I know in Ubuntu you can do:

> Ctrl + Alt + NumPad (1 to 9)

to get the screen to various corners. 1, 3, 7, 9, gets the screen into a nice quarter at the relevant corners.

I'm using a small keyboard without a number pad, how can I achieve the same effect without installing third party software?

I know you can do this too:

> Ctrl + Super + Arrow Keys

How I wish:

> Ctrl + Super + (Up + Left) or (Left + Up)

gets the screen to the top corner.

Any solutions?